# Shell script for deleting a word in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Can any one help me to develop the following script ?

I have following entry in /etc/httpd/httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.181:80> 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/  
 ServerName example.com 
 </VirtualHost>"
```

if some one enters an input example.com, I need to remove the same virtual host entry of example.com completely from the same file /etc/httpd/httpd.conf. How can i do this ?

Comment: Do you want to delete the complete section of <VirtualHost> .. </VirtualHost> ?

Comment: yes, I want to remove complete section of that virtual host

Comment: why is it so, do u have any solution for that

Comment: I trying something, but it doesn't work realy well in bash, i can it do in python but in bash i didn't get it

Comment: can u please in python

Comment: The problem is i don't really understand your problem exactly to give the compatible answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash script that will delete any `VirtualHost` block that contains the `domain` that matches the `domain` supplied as the 2nd argument to the program. The Script use is:

```
./scriptname /path/to/httpd.conf somedomain.com
```

The operation is straight forward. It will read through the existing httpd.conf creating a temporary httpd.conf in /tmp. It reads httpd.conf looking for any `VirtualHost` tags and then buffers all lines associated with them in an array. It tests whether `somedomain.com` is found in that `VirtualHost` block. If it is found, no writing to the new file occurs. If not found, then all lines of the `VirtualHost` block are written unchanged. Any other lines not associated with a `VirtualHost` block are simply written to the new file. After parsing, the new/old httpd.conf files are compared via diff. If they do not match, the new httpd.conf is written to the system httpd.conf location.

The script is commented below. let me know if you have further questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this file must be run as root
test "$UID" = 0 || {
    printf "\n  Error, insufficient privileges. root user required, user '%s' won't work.\n\n" "$USER"
    exit 1
}

## declare needed variables and flags
declare -a tmp                      # temp array to hold lines between <VirtualHost tags
declare -i loop=0                   # flag to loop over all line in <VirtualHost blocks
declare -i found=0                  # flag indicating domain to delete is found
tmstamp="$(date +%s)"               # unique timestamp for backup of httpd.conf
domain="${2:-example.com}"          # give domain to find as 2nd arg on command line
htfile="${1:-/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf}" # confirm path/filename for your setup
tmpfile="/tmp/httpd.conf.tmp"       # temp file to write remaining httpd.conf lines to
:> "$tmpfile"                       # truncate tmpfile

## backup httpd.conf, exit on err
cp -a "${htfile}" "${htfile}.$tmstamp" || {
    printf "\n Error, failed to make backup of httpd.conf.\n\n"
    exit 2
}

## NOTE: do not unset IFS, leave at default
#  read all lines in httpd.conf
while read -r line || test -n "$line"; do
    if test "${line:0:12}" == "<VirtualHost" || test $loop -eq 1 ; then  # if <VirtualHost found
        loop=1                                      # set loop flag to 1 to continue looping
        tmp+=( "$line" )                            # while looping add each line to tmp array
        test "${line##* }" == "$domain" && found=1  # if wanted domain found, set found flag=1
        if test "$line" == "</VirtualHost>" ; then  # if closing </VirtualHost tag found
            loop=0                                  # reset loop to 0
            if test "$found" -eq 1 ; then           # if 'found', just reset found flag (don't write)
                found=0
            else                                    # otherwise, write the VirtualHost block to file`
                for ((i=0; i<${#tmp[@]}; i++)); do
                    printf "%s\n" "${tmp[$i]}" >> "$tmpfile"
                done
            fi
            unset tmp                               # lastly - unset tmp array
        fi
    else                                            # Not in VirtualHost block, so
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$tmpfile"         # output all non-interesting lines to tmpfile
    fi
done <"$htfile"

## if new and old httpd.conf files differ, copy new to old
diff -qw &>/dev/null "$htfile" "$tmpfile" || cp -a "$tmpfile" "$htfile"

rm "$tmpfile"   # remove tmpfile

exit 0
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Bash is an amazing language for doing what it was made to do - anything needed in the administration of a Linux machine. It is hard to find something it doesn't do well. Well worth the time spent making friends with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter the domain' dom

NUM=$(cat -n /etc/httpd/httpd.conf |grep -w $dom|awk '{print $1}')
NUM1=$(($NUM-2))
NUM2=$(($NUM+1))
sed -i -e "$NUM1,$NUM2 d" /etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Fails with: `7-2: syntax error in expression (error token is "7-2")` and `7+1: syntax error in expression (error token is "7+1")` and `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: ','` **Additionally**, when modifying system configuration files, **always** keep a backup of the original file. Just in case your script doesn't do exactly what you think it does.

Comment: This is for Linux system and in Bash shell, Are you executing in the same platform or any other OS ?

Comment: Tested both on Archlinux and openSuSE.